# Getting all IP and MAC addresses on a network

Tags: .net, vb.net, ip-address, mac-address

Hi I am new on VB 2010 and trying to write simple WPF application which will detect all machines connected to local wireless network and list IP addresses and Mac addresses of this machines.

Comment: I deleted the OSX tag from your question, as Mac Adresses (despite the name) are not connected to machines running an Apple OS. If your question has an OSX specific background, feel free to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You can't detect conected machines to your LAN. Maybe you could try to ping machines in a range, but a response is not guaranteed. There is a Ping class included in the framework (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx) but the machine could be behind a firewall.

Please, note that some sysadmins could become angry if you ping a range of the network.

**EDIT**: If you're the SysAdmin and you're making this task for internal use, maybe you could connect (programatically) to the router via telnet and get the info.

Comment: Many Thanks for your answer. Since I am the sysadmin it won't be a problem. Can you give me a working simple example if you can please.

Comment: Of course. Check the marked answer of this other question in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751577/proper-way-to-scan-a-range-of-ip-addresses Its in C# ... but it is really easy to translate.